# Где лучше сортировать данные

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Где лучше (быстрее) сортировать данные в mysql или php ?

Comment: Вы бы и сами проверить могли. В MySQL - быстрее

Answer (score 1):

По существующим полям - mysql, по производным - по-разному. Например, сортировка по значениям, полученным при помощи нескольких вложенных функций, может затянуться весьма на длительное время.